# Minimum number of distinct elements after removing m items using R Scripting

Tags: r

Need guidance on how to start writing a code  to find minimum number of distinct elements after removing m items using R scripting.

I don't know where to start.

For example, there are n = 6 items, ids = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2], and the maximum number of items that can be deleted is m = 2.  Two possible actions are delete two items with ID = 2 or one with ID = 2 and one with ID = 3. Either way she will have 2 item IDs in the final bag: either ids = [1, 1, 1, 3] or ids = [1, 1, 1, 2].

Any guidance would really help me.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have a vector `x`, then `length(unique(x))` will tell you the number of distinct values in `x` (including `NA` if there are any).

Comment: @DaveArmstrong At first I thought that's what she was asking as well, but now I think the "minimum" versus "maximum" aspect makes it more complex. It sounds like she wants a function that considers a number of different possibilities and then finds the minimum `length(unique(x))` across those possibilities.

Comment: @Hack-R Ah, that is more complex.  In this particular example it would be easy, because it sounds like there are only two possibilities - the two mentioned in the question.  However, if this needs to be more general, we would need to know the details of the algorithm that results in the removal of IDs.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question rigth you can solve this as follow :

(I'm using the library dplyr)

First step is to count how many times each id appears :

```
library(dplyr)

m <- 2
dat <- tibble(id = c(1,1,1,2,3,2))

comptage <- dat %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Witch gives you :

```
> comptage
# A tibble: 3 x 2
     id     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     3
2     2     2
3     3     1
```

Then to find how many id you can remove, you arrange your table by "n" (the count variable) and keep only the id having a cumulative sum over or egal to the limit m of removal number :

```
comptage <- comptage %>% 
  arrange(n) %>% 
  mutate(sum_cum = cumsum(n))

> comptage
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     id     n sum_cum
  <dbl> <int>   <int>
1     3     1       1
2     2     2       3
3     1     3       6

result <- comptage %>% 
  filter(!sum_cum < m)

> result
# A tibble: 2 x 3
     id     n sum_cum
  <dbl> <int>   <int>
1     2     2       3
2     1     3       6

length(result$id)
```

This is probably not the easiest way to do it but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to define a function `f`

```
f <- function(ids, m) {
  u <- table(ids)
  while (m > 0) {
    k <- which.min(u)
    u <- subset(v <- replace(u, k, u[k] - 1), v > 0)
    m <- m - 1
  }
  rep(as.numeric(names(u)), u)
}
```

which removes the first `m` "low-occurrence" elements from `ids`, there `table` helps to summarize the  occurrence of each unique elements in `ids`.

**Example**

```
> f(ids,1)
[1] 1 1 1 2 2

> f(ids,2)
[1] 1 1 1 2

> f(ids,3)
[1] 1 1 1
```